# How many branches are in a (a && b) statement? According to gcov: 4

Tags: c, gcc, code-coverage, gcov

I compiled the following program with "gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage test.c":

```
int main() {
  int a = 1;
  int b = 1;
  a && b;
}
```

After running the program, an invocation of "gcov -bc test.c" reports that 50% of 4 branches were taken at least once. Why does gcov say the program has four branches, instead of two? After running the following program, gcov correctly reports that 50% of 2 branches were taken at least once:

```
int main() {
  int a = 1;
  if (a)
    a = 0;
  else
    a = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `gcov` is considering `a&&b` to be the following:

```
if(a) { // branch 1
    if(b) { // branch 2
        1; 
    } else { // branch 3
        0;
    }
} else { // branch 4
    0;
}
```

Though I'm fairly certain the actual CPU instructions will translate to a single branch.

Comment: Yes, the actual assembler output contains just one conditional branch. The rationale of why gcov chooses to interpret branch coverage of short-circuiting operators this way is not clear to me.

Comment: The interpretation as "if (a) { result = b; } else { result = 0; }" would seem more reasonable to me (result denotes the result of a && b).

Comment: @HermannSpeiche: That's incorrect. The result of `a && b` is 0 or 1, not 0 or `b`.